# Removing app from data calculation

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring, app-data, data-plan

I have a subscription that makes Spotify not count towards my data cap.

Thing is, when I go in my data usage calculations on my phone, it still is counted.

[image]
[image]

Any way to remove an app from the data cap count on the phone?

PS: If I look into my account on the provider website, I have something like 200mb used.

PPS: Running a One Plus One, Android 6.0.1 with Cyanogen 13.0, I think I'm rooted, but not sure.

[image]

Also sorry, I don't know how to limit the size of my image.

Comment: I dont want to restrict the data use (I have to use the data to play spotify) I just want my phone not to count spotify when it calculates the total amount of data used... so when I look at the graph, I have a much more accurate representation of what's left in my data, and not have to guess based on how much Spotify uses.

Comment: I don't think you can remove the projection of an app using data in the Settings->Data Usage page. It isn't a function provided by the Settings app.